# Unable to get the correct encoding after decryption with XOR-cipher

Tags: ruby, encryption, character-encoding

Given ciphertext `7b5a4215415d544115415d5015455447414c155c46155f4058455c5b523f`
xored with `151515151515151515151515151515151515151515151515151515151515` I get `6e4f57005448415400544845005041525459004953004a554d50494e472a` (no rocket science here).

Now, I'm trying to decode this hex encoded string to a normal string - the result should be `Now that the party is jumping\n`. Unfortunately, it is

```
irb(main):012:0> ["6e4f57005448415400544845005041525459004953004a554d50494e472a"].pack('H*')
=> "nOW\x00THAT\x00THE\x00PARTY\x00IS\x00JUMPING*"
```

It's close enough for me to decipher it, but also bad enough to score bad given an English letter frequency evaluator.

For all of my previous strings I've used `[str].pack('H*')`and it went well. For example

```
irb(main):004:0> ["54686520717569636b2062726f776e20666f78206a756d7073206f76657220746865206c617a7920646f672e"].pack('H*')
=> "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
```

I'm guessing the new dataset has some bizarre encoding I am unable to decipher and handle.

Any Ruby ideas?

Comment: That's pretty strange. How was the cipher text produced? Can you share the code you used to do the XORing?

Comment: Cryptopals challenge 4? It’s not the encoding, there’s a better key – you need to improve your English scoring procedure.

Comment: It's not an encoding issue, your string has NULL bytes in it. `\x00` is ASCII for NULL.

Comment: Matt, you're right. And because of that, my question is invalid. Thanks!

Comment: Changed the title a bit to indicate more precisely what this is about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably just have to XOR your key stream (and therefore ciphertext) with 0x20. That will both turn uppercase into lowercase and zeros in to spaces (0x20).

So the key is 0x35 instead of 0x15.